# Include javascript from module in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2-dev-beta

I had created module magento 2 with this sample : URL:
https://www.ashsmith.io/2014/12/simple-magento2-controller-module/

I have spent more time review default module of magento 2 and research "Include javascript from module to magento 2.
I have tried:
**layout/default.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="authentication-popup">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="hello" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">ABC_Hello/js/hello</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            captcha: 'ABC_Hello/hello'
        }
    }
};
```

**frontend/web/hello.js** or **frontend/hello.js**

```
define([
    "jquery"
], function($) {
    "use strict";

    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert('Test JS');
    });
});
```

but it not work.

Thanks any tips??

**Update**
**Resolved**
My Layout: **hello_index_index.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Hello magento 2</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="ABC\Hello\Block\Hello" name="hello" template="ABC_Hello::hello.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**default.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="authentication-popup">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="hello" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">ABC_Hello/js/hello</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**layout/web/hello.js**
Code javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please, update your **layout/default.xml** file with following content:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="authentication-popup">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="hello" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Tax/js/hello</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Move **frontend/web/hello.js** or **frontend/hello.js** to new location: **frontend/web/js/hello.js** and update **hello.js** file with following content:

```
define(
[
    'jquery',
    'uiComponent'
],
function ($, Component) {
    'use strict';

    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert('Test JS');
    });
    return Component.extend({});
});
```

Now you can clean Magento cache and refresh the page. You will see your alert. Please, let me know if this works for you. 
Thanks

Comment: It not work :(, can you help me some demo ??

Comment: Sorry, there is a typo in layout **Magento_Tax/js/hello**. Please, use **Forix_Hello/js/hello**

Comment: I was change it in first times of answer, but it not work.

Comment: Can I download the whole code of your extension on github to analyze the issue? I tried different variations on my local and it always works. Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/thien321091/Curl-FTP-with-php 

Code has been up to github, checkout file **Forix.zip**

Comment: I've installed your extension on my local for EE and CE. It works. I can see alter "sdfsdf". Please, check your requirejs-config.js file under pub/static/_requirejs/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/requirejs-config.js. This file should contain this line:  hello: "Forix_Hello/js/hello". If not, please, remove this file and refresh the page. It will be generated again.

Comment: On more question: Do you have some errors in browser console?

Comment: Oh this working fine. after I applied solution in answer.

Comment: Good to know. I want to recommend you to clean up these directories after changes in templates and JS files: var/*cache, var/view_preprocessed/*, pub/static/* to avoid such issues in a future.

Comment: Thank's very much !!!. I will focus it :3

Answer (score 1):

try php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: it mean deploy css, js for front-end.