# Adding TypeKit code (or any code) into the Head of a Magento 2 site

Tags: magento2, head

All I want to do is to add a custom font from TypeKit into my Magento 2 website.

Previously I just used to find /app/design/frontend/XXX/XXX/page/head.phtml and edit that. Simple.

With Magento 2 it seems to be hugely complicated. [I keep finding articles like this](http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_javascript_css_layout_woes). Do I really need to create an entire Module just to add 2 lines of basic HTML to the head of a document?

Surely there must be an easier way?

[I found this similar question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86243/add-custom-js-in-head-in-magento2), but I dont get the answer. Where do I create a layout file in my theme? Or is it suggesting I create a whole seperate Module again?

[I also found this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/75106/include-javascript-from-module-in-magento-2), and it looks insane. Am I right in thinking that they are editing 3 seperate files, jsut to add a JS file into head?

Surely this cant be right? Isn't there a `head.phtml` file I can just edit?

Can someone break this down for me, assume I am an idiot, and explain how I can easily just add 2 lines of TypeKit code to the Head. Many thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no need to create extension just to add script in head. You can use following setting from admin.

Login to admin and navigate to following :

**UPDATE:**

In Magento 2.0, the Miscellaneous Scripts feature was located under the
**`Admin > Stores > Configuration > General > Design > HTML head`**
And find **Miscellaneous Scripts**

Add Your Typekit/Custom script here in **Miscellaneous Scripts** textarea and **Save Config**.

---

In Magento 2.1, this feature was relocated to the **`Admin > Content > Design > Configuration Tab`**. You will then need to select the Scope for which you wish to make the changes. In the **`Other Settings`** section, select the **`HTML Head`** Tab.

Add Your Typekit/Custom script here in **Scripts and Style Sheets** textarea and **Save Config**.

**Note**: Don't forget to clear cache

Hope it helps you

Comment: This seems to be the instructions for M1, whereas the question is tagged for M2; see Anshu's answer instead.

Comment: @AlexHadley The Old answer is for Magento 2.0 version. I've updated it for Magento 2.0 as well

Answer (score 2):

To add using layout xml rather than database configuration use the following in `app/design/frontend/<vendor_name>/<theme_name>/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="https://use.typekit.net/xxxxxxx.js" src_type="url" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text" name="typekit">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="text" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[<script>try{Typekit.load({ async: true });}catch(e){}</script>]]></argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 1):

Script can be added in the admin.

**`Go to Content -> Configuration (Under Design) -> Click on Edit (Required Theme) -> Html Head -> Scripts and Style Sheets`**

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2.2.6 you need to:

1. login to the **Admin panel**
2. select **`CONTENT > Configuration`** *(under **Design** heading)*
3. edit your **Store View** record
4. add your code in **`HTML Head > Scripts and Style Sheets`** *(under **Other Settings** heading)*
5. Save Configuration
6. Refresh Configuration cache

[image: <code>CONTENT > Configuration</code> menu]